# Rails: List of categories where related items count is greater than 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails model:
Categories have items

Trying to get a list of categories that actually have items.

Something like:

```
@categories = Category.where(category.items.count > 0).all
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails 3?

```
Category.joins(:items).select('distinct categories.*')
```

should work.

Comment: (and @jmc) - He'll most likely also need a `.group('category.id')` in there as well. By the way, this works because mysql doesn't return rows that have no partners in an inner join.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. I'd suggest .select('distinct categories.*') personally as it will work better with postgres. Will add that to my answer.

Comment: How about if you want to do it with `count > 1`?

Comment: This returns a relation that has a wrong count() which is not such a big deal except if you try to paginate these (for example with will_paginate) then it has the wrong idea of how many items there actually are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a terminal right now, so I can't test this.. but I think it should work:

```
Items.find(:all).categories.uniq
```

This will return any category which is associated with an `Item` object (so, `items.count > 0`).